# What is the code to ask a user to input a number and print the square and cube of that number in python 3.5?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 3.5.2 and have been asked to write a small program to ask a user to enter a number and the program will then print out the square and the cube of the number entered. This is the code I've written so far:

```
 number = input ('Please enter a number ')
 y = (number)**2
 z = (number)**3
 print (y+z)
```

and when I run it I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

What is the correct code to get this to work?

Comment: `input` always returns a string (in Python 3) and you can't do arithmetic on strings, so you must convert to a numeric type, e.g. `number = int(input('please enter a number'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when in doubt, add print statements

```
number = input ('Please enter a number ')
print("number is %s of type %s" % (number, type(number)))
print("number is {} of type {}".format(number, type(number)))

y = number ** 2
print("y is {} of type {}".format(y, type(y)))

z = number **3
print("z is {} of type {}".format(z, type(z)))

print (y+z)
```

Output:

```
python3 x.py
Please enter a number 4
number is 4 of type <class 'str'>
number is 4 of type <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 5, in <module>
    y = number ** 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

AS you can see, number is a string because in python3, `input` returns the users input as a string

change it to `int(input('Please enter a number'))`

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite self-explanatory :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

Basically `(number)`is a string while `2`is an integer. What you need to do is convert `number` from `str` to `int`.
Try this :

```
y = int(number) ** 2
z = int(number) ** 3
print(y+z)
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and the suggestion above and they both solved the issue i was having.